# typed xml in sql - is this possible?

Tags: xml, t-sql, select

I've a table with a typed XML field. Typical XML format is:

```
<root>
  <users>
      <user name="John Doe" />
      <user name="Alexander" />
   </users>
   <apps>
      <app name="Office 2010" />
      <app name="SQL Server 2005" />
   <apps>
</root>
```

Assuming this table has 25 rows with different values in the users and apps elements, is there a way to:

1. Retrieve the list of all users in the /root/users element for all the records.
2. Retrieve the list of all users + application for all the records.

SQL on this line works but gives me only first user name.

```
SELECT xtbl.col1.value('(user/@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') 
FROM mytable
     CROSS APPLY xmlcol.nodes('/root/users') AS xtbl(col1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nodes` function is selecting one row per `users`, but you're looking for one row per `user`.  Try:

```
SELECT xtbl.col1.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') 
FROM mytable
     CROSS APPLY xmlcol.nodes('/root/users/user') AS xtbl(col1)
```

Comment: Fantastic - thank you. It worked. Adding another CROSS APPLY on app node did the trick for the second one also. Thanks again.